# How to add keyframes for multiple objects at once

Tags: animation, workflow

I've got about 200 objects for which I want to insert location/rotation keyframes.

Is there a way to add a keyframe for all of the selected objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about actual objects (not a mix of objects and armature bones), the easiest thing would be to select all of the objects and, from within the 3D View, press <kbd>`I`</kbd> and choose LocRot. That will insert a key for location and rotation on all selected objects.

If your needs are more nuanced, you may want to consider building a custom keying set. In that, you can specify any number of different properties from any number of objects (and non-objects... like World properties) and key them all at the same time. If you're interested in taking that route, then [Getting to Grips with Keying Sets](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2010/12/getting-to-grips-with-keying-sets/) is a good start.

Comment: Nice! I've always been adding keyframes by right clicking on properties in the object menu :)

Comment: why does this not work all the time and just sometimes!?

Answer (score 10):

### Keying Sets

As [Fweeb said](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1622/290), the standard way of handling this is using *Keying Sets*. Accessible in the *3D View* under *Object > Animation > Insert Keyframe…* (<kbd>`I`</kbd>). There's [a limited set by default](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Keyframes#Creating_Keyframes) but custom ones can be added. For more info see: [Can I personalize the insert keyframe menu?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2063/290)

### Scripting

Any time a task would be repetitive to do by hand, scripting is a good choice. Here's a quick example of how to insert a keyframe to all the objects in a selection:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.scale[2] = 0.5 # Set Z scale.
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale", index=2) # Keyframe it.
```

`obj.keyframe_insert` doesnt work in recent version of blender, this does `obj.data.keyframe_insert`

### Linked Animation datablocks

If creating the same animation on all object, you can animate just the active object and then link the action to the rest of the selection: *Object > Make links… (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) > Animation Data)*. If you wish to later mix in some unique animation, [turn the action into a NLA strip](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA#Creating_Action_Strips) before linking.

Answer (score 1):

There is this commercial add-on, **[Key Selected Objects](https://blastframe.com/product/key-selected-objects/)**, if you want to add/delete keys for multiple objects from the user interface.:
[image: Key Selected Objects]