# Can I personalize the insert keyframe menu?

Tags: animation, customization

In my animation I use a lot of restrict render and restrict view on/off.
Can I do something to display those keyframes when I type the <kbd>I</kbd> key *(insert keyframe menu)*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's done using [Keying Sets](http://aligorith.blogspot.fr/2010/12/animating-in-25-getting-to-grips-with.html):

> ### Types of Keying Sets
>
> There are basically two types of Keying Set in Blender: "Builtin" and "Absolute".
>
> **Builtin** are the ones that are always available (context permitting) in Blender. They are the (familiar) ones that show up in the IKEY menu by default - "Location", "Rotation", "Scaling", and friends. All you generally need to know about these are that they are defined using in Python so that they can check the context to see what properties they should act on. This means that you CAN'T add/remove properties from them yourself unless you edit the Python code which determines what they use. If you're curious to add a few more 'builtins' that you commonly like to use, you can find these under scripts/keyingsets/ in your install directory. Be aware though that the attempts at making these definitions quite "modular" may initially be a little confusing for novice/beginner Python programmers, though they should still be quite easy to grasp. The topic of setting these up shall be left as an exercise to the reader and/or a future post :)
>
> **Absolute** are the ones that you should be most interested in, as they are the "user-defined" Keying Sets, and are stored per Scene (that they are defined for). By setting up and using these carefully, you can improve your workflow quite a bit. Used appropriately, you can insert keyframes for a whole bunch of related properties with the touch of a key (or single click if you like), saving frustration from forgetting to key one of a bunch of properties and saving time jumping around keying multiple things separately. This has significant benefits, especially for the modern character animator working in the standard pose-to-pose full-pose blocking method, where keying every single control on every key-pose at once is the método comodo.

See the documentation written by the developer of this feature for more info:

- [Getting to grips with Keying Sets](http://aligorith.blogspot.fr/2010/12/animating-in-25-getting-to-grips-with.html)
- [Coding your own "Builtin Keying Set"](http://aligorith.blogspot.fr/2011/02/extending-25-coding-your-own-builtin.html)