# How to get a group of many rigid bodies to start simulation at a set frame

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, groups

I have a physics simulation in Blender with many rigid bodies. I have a group containing many objects (255). How do I turn off physics simulation on this group of objects to until a certain frame?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2620/599