# How do I prevent rigid body objects from falling down before they are hit?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have done BlenderGuru's [Quick Rigid Body Fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY) on Rigid Body Collisions.

[image]

Regarding this .blend file:

[image]

When you play the animation, the cubes start falling down long before they are hit by the wrecking ball. This is because of gravity and because there is some space between the cubes. How can you prevent the cubes falling down or at least arrange that the cubes don't fall down before they are hit by the wrecking ball?

P.S Blender Guru says it is necessary to have some space between the cubes because if there is no space the wall will explode. I have here another .blend file...

[image]

...where there is no space between the cubes, so I don't think he is right. But the stones don't behave like there is a wall .... hmmmm ???

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/insert-properties-keyframe-for-multiple-objects

Comment: You need to reset the origin points of the cubes after you separate them from the arrays they were part of. They fall because the origin point is at the same place for all of them once you separate them. he explains to use Ctrl-Alt-Shift-C > Geometry to Origin, but when I do it, the cubes all end up at the same location, so I don't know what's up with that.

Comment: The reason I couldn't change the origin points was because I had rigid body physics turned on. I had to turn it off for the cubes first.

Comment: Now my physics isn't working at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer to this is to *apply transforms* to all of the cubes. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*>Scale* and then in the physics panel, *enable deactivation* and *start deactivated* for all cubes so that the simulation does not take over the objects until they interact. Just enable the option for one, then choose *copy from active* in the *Tool shelf* with all cubes selected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems to work and a indeed a simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I started with the first linked .blend file. After my short, 14-step method, I achieved this:

[image]

1. Make sure all the cubes and the cubes only are selected. The active object must be a cube.
2. Go to frame 85.
3. Go to the *Properties panel > Physics tab > Rigid Body dropdown* and uncheck the *Dynamic* checkbox.
4. Hover over the *Dynamic* checkbox and key <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe. It should turn from grey to yellow.
5. Key <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to move to frame 86.
6. Go to the *Properties panel > Physics tab > Rigid Body dropdown* and check the *Dynamic* checkbox.
7. Hover over the *Dynamic* checkbox and key <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe. It should turn from green to yellow.
8. Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> to go back to frame 1. Any simulated physics should have gone away.
9. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join all of the cubes.
10. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*.
11. Key <kbd>P</kbd> to open the *Separate* menu and either key <kbd>3</kbd> or manually select *By Loose Parts*. All of the cubes should now have the aforeinserted (heh) keyframes.
12. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.
13. Select all cubes, if they are not already selected.
14. Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to open the *Origin* menu and select *Origin to Geometry*.

Here is the finished .blend file that produced the .gif at the beginning:

[image]

Comment: This is more like a workaround than a real solution. As animation data is handled with, the only thing left is to link it. Already given solution - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/insert-properties-keyframe-for-multiple-objects

Comment: @ShadyPuck do not really understand your comments, or did I miss something ?

Comment: @OldMan Lemon was here earlier, and we were discussing the fact that I forgot to write up steps 12-14. Lemon is someone who prefers to delete their comments after posting. If my answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: @ShadyPuck so your solution is essentially to work with keyframes and exclude the cubes from the animation till they get hit by using keyframes and the Dynamic check box ? The part that I don't understand is al joining, separating of the cubes (step 10 -14). I mean I already did separate the cubes and did set the origins, did not I ?

Comment: @OldMan The joining and separating copies the keyframes from one object to every object.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Although I prefer the Timaroberts answer I think it is good to know the solution you propose. So I would suggest to keep your answer. Thanks