# How do I add a property Keyframe such as Diffuse Intensity to all selected objects

Tags: keyframes

If I select all objects in a scene and add a location keyframe, all objects will get a location keyframe. How do I do the same thing with a property such as Diffuse Intensity. If I am animating 100 cubes for example and want to add a Diffuse Intensity Keyframe I can't seem to do it to all selected objects simultaneously. I understand I could probably do it by adding all 100 Diffuse Intensity properties to a Keying Set but is there another way other than scripting it? I tried ctrl L > "Copy Animation Data" and this doesn't seem to work.
Thanks

Comment: Do all 100 cubes have the same material? If so, you should just be able to keyframe the one.

Comment: be carefull about which objects you select last before copying animation data. It will have a more vivid orange tone than selected objects and it means is is the "active" object, this has influence for the source and destination targets during a copy operation.

Comment: I guess this could be done with some python-fu scripting, see this (although different) for inspiration: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27136/how-to-copy-keyframes-from-one-action-to-other, there are other similar questions, too. See also this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2636/919

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided the easiest way to do it was through a script. I was just surprised there wasn't a method as simple as adding location keyframes. Just getting the hang of scripting and enjoying it's powers.